# Mongoose gives validation error even when required fields are present

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using the mongoose ODM for a project. My schema looks like this:

```
const applicantSchema = new Schema({
  regno: {
  type: String,
  unique: true,
  required: true
  },
  email: {
  type: String,
  unique: true,
  required: true
  }
});

const Applicant = mongoose.model('Applicant', applicantSchema);
```

I created a wrapper function to add a new document which looks like this:

```
function addApplicant(newApplicant, callback){
  mongoose.connect(url);

  const db = mongoose.connection;

  console.log(newApplicant);
  console.log(typeof newApplicant);

  const applicant = new Applicant(newApplicant);

  applicant.save((err) => {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    let info = "successfully saved target"; 
    return callback(null, info);
  });
}
```

I call this function within my route that handles the concerned post request.

```
router.post('/applicant/response', (req, res) => {
  //process sent response here and add to DB
  //console.log(req.body);
  let newApplicant = {
    regno: req.body.regno,
    email: req.body.email
  }
  //console.log(newApplicant);

  applicant.addApplicant(newApplicant, (err, info) => {
    if(err){ console.log(err); res.end(err);}
    res.end('complete, resp: ' + info);
  });
});
```

However, mongoose gives me a validation error (path 'regno' is required) even though I am supplying a value for regno. This happens with all the fields marked as required.

If I remove the 'required: true' option the document is saved to the db as expected.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution to this? I have a simple Category Schema with one field "name". Whenever I Remove `required: true`, I don't get any errors but it's not adding the "name" field

Comment: Hi @Hadh, I've answered my question with what worked for me. It's an issue with how postman sends data. The code in the question worked for me without any changes when I tested it as described in the answer. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi, yes it was a postman issue, all I did was set the context type to json in the headers of postman and it worked just fine.. took me around an hour and my code was okay hhahh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that in this case, something was wrong with the way postman was sending data in a POST request. When I tested this later in postman using JSON as the data format (and ensuring that the Content-Type header is set to application/json), the code worked as expected.

To those facing a similar issue, check the headers postman sends with the request, and ensure that they are what you'd expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

In your express entry file where you expose your endpoints and setup express you should have `app.use(express.json());` written above the endpoint.

```js
const express = require("express");
require("./src/db/mongoose");

const User = require("./src/models/user");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// THIS LINE IS MANDATORY
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/users", async(req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);

  try {
    await user.status(201).save();

    res.send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is runnung in port ${port}`);
});
```